# A good tool for browser automation/client-side Web scripting

Tags: security, scripting, browser, web-scraping

I'm interested in adopting a tool/scripting language to automate some daily tasks connected with fighting forum spammers.  A brief overview of these tasks: analyze new registrations and posts on a phpBB forum, and delete or deactivate spammers using [a website/community that collects such spam reports](http://www.stopforumspam.com/).

Typically such automation is integrated into the phpBB installation itself, which certainly has its advantages.  My approach has the advantage of independent operation, etc.

One way to think about this is in terms of browser automation.  I've used iOpus iMacros for Firefox ([the free version](http://www.iopus.com/imacros/firefox/)) in the past to respond to individual spammers, but current attacks are highly distributed.  My "logic" for pigeonholing spammers vs. nonspammers seems beyond the easy reach of the free version of iMacros.

From a more technical perspective one can think about dispensing with the browser altogether and programming GET/POST requests directed to my forum and other Web-based resources.

I'm familiar with some scripting languages like Ruby and Lua, but I could be persuaded that a compiled application is better suited for these tasks.  However in my experience the dynamic flexibility of interpreted environments is very useful in prototyping and debugging the application logic.  So I'm leaning in the direction of scripting languages.

Among browsers I favor Firefox and Chrome. I use both Windows and Linux platforms, and if the tool can adapt to an Android platform, it would make a neat demonstration of skills, yes?

Thanks in advance for your suggestions!

Comment: Are you looking for any current browser automation tool? Any specific constraints?

Comment: @Oded:  Open source would be better than otherwise, but no specific constraints.  I do find iMacros lacks the power I need to interact with more than one URL in concert, but this may be my ignorance of its true capabilities.

Comment: I assume you don't have access to the phpbb server to do this directly to the backend or simply install a plugin with an appropriate situation... Cause otherwise it's extremely inefficient in all meanings of the word to do this via browser automation.

Comment: @Matthieu:  I'm puzzled as to why a question exists about relating "to software development" in closing this question.  Tools like selenium and Watir mentioned in the answers are certainly software development tools.  It's frankly bizarre that you'd close this more than a month after an answer was accepted.

Comment: @MarkTrapp:  Please note my comment above.  I'd appreciate some insight on your vote to close.

Comment: Please read the [rest of the FAQ](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq): "If you have a question [...] and it is **not about…** programming tools (ask on Stack Overflow instead) …then you're in the right place to ask your question!"

Comment: @MarkTrapp: Thanks for the courtesy of your reply.  I believe you have misunderstood that point in the FAQ, but I'll mention my concern on meta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not entirely sure I understood what you are looking for, but [selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) is widely used for web automation.

There are some tools that help with using selenium - [capybara](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara) is a ruby based tool that simplifies such work.

Comment: +1 Selenium absolutely rocks.  Plus you can use the recorder to record the majority of what you want to do and export the code to C#, Java, and a ton of other languages.

Answer (score 1):

I have used Watir for all the automated testing at a big electronics company and found it really great to work with, especially because the excellent Ruby language is used.